# Как правильно объединять изображения при помощи OpenCV в андроид?

Tags: java, android, opencv

Пишу функционал для объединения изображений с пересекающимися областями. Использовал наработки [отсюда](http://answers.opencv.org/question/27681/image-stitching-java-api/).

Сам код:

```
static Mat image1;
static Mat image2;
static Mat img1;
static Mat img2;

static FeatureDetector fd;
static DescriptorExtractor fe;
static DescriptorMatcher fm;

public void init(){

    fd = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.BRISK);
    fe = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.BRISK);
    fm = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE);
    System.out.println("---->> 1");

    //images
    try {
        img1 = Utils.loadResource(context, R.drawable.image1, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
        img2 = Utils.loadResource(context, R.drawable.image2, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
        System.out.println("---->> 2");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("-------======= Ошибка загрузки изображений =======-------");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    image1 = new Mat();
    image2 = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img1, image1, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img2, image2, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    //structures for the keypoints from the 2 images
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

    System.out.println("---->> 3");
    //structures for the computed descriptors
    Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
    Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();

    //structure for the matches
    MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();

    //getting the keypoints
    fd.detect(image1, keypoints1);
    fd.detect(image2, keypoints2);

    //getting the descriptors from the keypoints
    fe.compute(image1, keypoints1, descriptors1);
    fe.compute(image2,keypoints2,descriptors2);

    //getting the matches the 2 sets of descriptors
    fm.match(descriptors2,descriptors1, matches);

    //turn the matches to a list
    List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();

    Double maxDist = 0.0; //keep track of max distance from the matches
    Double minDist = 100.0; //keep track of min distance from the matches

    //calculate max & min distances between keypoints
    for(int i=0; i<keypoints1.rows();i++){
        Double dist = (double) matchesList.get(i).distance;
        if (dist<minDist) minDist = dist;
        if(dist>maxDist) maxDist=dist;
    }

    System.out.println("max dist: " + maxDist );
    System.out.println("min dist: " + minDist);

    //structure for the good matches
    LinkedList<DMatch> goodMatches = new LinkedList<DMatch>();

    //use only the good matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist)
    for(int i=0;i<descriptors1.rows();i++){
        KeyPoint kp[] = keypoints1.toArray();
        KeyPoint kp2[] = keypoints2.toArray();
        Point point1 = kp[matchesList.get(i).queryIdx].pt;
        Point point2 = kp2[matchesList.get(i).trainIdx].pt;
        if(matchesList.get(i).distance<3*minDist){

                goodMatches.addLast(matchesList.get(i));

        }
    }

    //structures to hold points of the good matches (coordinates)
    LinkedList<Point> objList = new LinkedList<Point>(); // image1
    LinkedList<Point> sceneList = new LinkedList<Point>(); //image 2

    List<KeyPoint> keypoints_objectList = keypoints1.toList();
    List<KeyPoint> keypoints_sceneList = keypoints2.toList();

    //putting the points of the good matches into above structures
    for(int i = 0; i<goodMatches.size(); i++){
        objList.addLast(keypoints_objectList.get(goodMatches.get(i).queryIdx).pt);
        sceneList.addLast(keypoints_sceneList.get(goodMatches.get(i).trainIdx).pt);
    }

    System.out.println("\nNum. of good matches" +goodMatches.size());

    MatOfDMatch gm = new MatOfDMatch();
    gm.fromList(goodMatches);

    //converting the points into the appropriate data structure
    MatOfPoint2f obj = new MatOfPoint2f();
    obj.fromList(objList);

    MatOfPoint2f scene = new MatOfPoint2f();
    scene.fromList(sceneList);

    //finding the homography matrix
     Mat H = Calib3d.findHomography(obj, scene, Calib3d.RANSAC, 1);

    //LinkedList<Point> cornerList = new LinkedList<Point>();
    Mat obj_corners = new Mat(4,1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
    Mat scene_corners = new Mat(4,1, CvType.CV_32FC2);

    obj_corners.put(0,0, new double[]{0,0});
    obj_corners.put(0,0, new double[]{image1.cols(),0});
    obj_corners.put(0,0,new double[]{image1.cols(),image1.rows()});
    obj_corners.put(0,0,new double[]{0,image1.rows()});

    Core.perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

    //structure to hold the result of the homography matrix
    Mat result = new Mat();

    //size of the new image - i.e. image 1 + image 2
    Size s = new Size(image1.cols()+image2.cols(),image1.rows());

    //using the homography matrix to warp the two images
    Imgproc.warpPerspective(image1, result, H, s);
    int i = image1.cols();
    Mat m = new Mat(result,new Rect(i,0,image2.cols(), image2.rows()));

    image2.copyTo(m);

    Mat img_mat = new Mat();

    Features2d.drawMatches(image1, keypoints1, image2, keypoints2, gm, img_mat, new Scalar(254,0,0),new Scalar(254,0,0) , new MatOfByte(), 2);

   Bitmap bmp1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(result.cols(), result.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(result, bmp1);
   Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(img_mat.cols(), img_mat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); Utils.matToBitmap(img_mat, bmp2); String download_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath();
    File file = new File(download_path, "imageStitched.jpg");
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    System.out.println("-------======= "+ download_path +" =======-------");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) fos.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

В результате получаю вот это[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя должно быть вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку

P.S На монохромность не обращайте внимание, это не ошибка.

**UPD** 
Нашел основную ошибку, дело было в строке: fm.match(descriptors2,descriptors1, matches); надо было поменять местами первый и второй параметр.

Теперь ключевые точки находятся верно:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но есть проблема с объединением изображений[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Картинки для объединения  были взяты отсюда https://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/11/22/panorama-image-stitching-in-opencv/

Comment: А в чём ошибка то? Опишите ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Результатом должно было быть объединение двух изображений в одно с учетом пересекающихся областей как в этом примере https://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/11/22/panorama-image-stitching-in-opencv/

Comment: Может быть в строке `fd.detect(image1, keypoints2);` заменить `image1` на `image2`?

Comment: @post_zeew исправил, но к сожалению это не решило проблему

Comment: Пробовали ли использовать `SURF` и `FLANN`, как это делается в [оригинале](https://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/11/22/panorama-image-stitching-in-opencv/) примера?

Comment: @alexis031182 к сожалению ни SURF ни FLANN, на сколько я понял, в андроид дистрибутиве OpenCV не поддерживаются, да и нашел я основную ошибку, сейчас обновлю вопрос